# MatrixTransform inside MatrixTransform behavior is not what I was expecting

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, zooming, transform, matrix-inverse

I currently have a Border that is bound to a MatrixTransform.  When scrolling the mouse wheel, it will basically scale the MatrixTransform.  Inside of the border, I have a Rectangle that is centered horizontally and vertically.  At the time when the Border transform is scaled, I set the transform of the Rectangle to be equal to the Inverse of the Border.  The ides is to keep the rectangle the same size and in the center.  My current solution will keep the rectangle the same size, but it gradually moves away from center as you keep zooming. It seems as if the Rectangle transform isn't aware of the Border transform, does that make sense?

Here's a couple images, the first is initial, the second is after zooming a couple times (notice the rectangle stayed the same size, but it's no longer centered).

[image]

[image]

The basic idea that I'm trying to solve is like a Google maps application, when you zoom in, the city name size stays the same.

Here's all of my code, you should be able to pull this in and run it if you'd like:

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="InvertedZoomTest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InvertedZoomTest"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:MainPage_ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Border BorderBrush="Pink" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="2" MouseWheel="Border_MouseWheel" Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransform="{Binding MainTransform}">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Canvas.Top="43" Canvas.Left="43" Fill="Red" Height="10" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransform="{Binding TextTransform}"/>
</Border>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MainPage_ViewModel viewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.DataContext as MainPage_ViewModel;
        }
    }

    private void Border_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            this.viewModel.ZoomRatio += .1;
        }
        else
        {
            this.viewModel.ZoomRatio -= .1;
        }

        this.viewModel.UpdateTextScale();
    }
}
```

MainPage_ViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPage_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MatrixTransform TextTransform
    {
        get { return _textTransform; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _textTransform)
            {
                _textTransform = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TextTransform");
            }
        }
    }
    private MatrixTransform _textTransform = new MatrixTransform();

    public MatrixTransform MainTransform
    {
        get
        {
            return _mainTransform;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _mainTransform)
            {
                _mainTransform = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MainTransform");
            }
        }
    }
    private MatrixTransform _mainTransform = new MatrixTransform();

    public void UpdateTextScale()
    {
        var scaleX = (double)(ZoomRatio);
        var scaleY = (double)(ZoomRatio);

        Matrix updatedMainTransformMatrix = new Matrix(scaleX, 0, 0, scaleY, 0, 0);
        this.MainTransform.Matrix = updatedMainTransformMatrix;
        OnPropertyChanged("MainTransform");

        this.TextTransform = MainTransform.Inverse as MatrixTransform;
        OnPropertyChanged("TextTransform");
    }

    public double ZoomRatio
    {
        get
        {
            return zoomRatio;
        }
        set
        {
            zoomRatio = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ZoomRatio");

            UpdateTextScale();
        }
    }
    private double zoomRatio = 1;


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that would make this rectangle move from the center?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Out of curiousity, I wrapped a border around the rectangle and did an element to element binding on the width & height.  You will notice in the image below that the transform on the rectangle seems to have an origin at the top left, does this make sense?

New XAML:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Pink" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="2" MouseWheel="Border_MouseWheel" Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransform="{Binding MainTransform}">
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Height="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Width}">
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Canvas.Top="43" Canvas.Left="43" Fill="Red" Height="10" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransform="{Binding TextTransform}"/>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

Resulting Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  I just needed to set the RenderTransformOrigin of my rectangle to the center.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Pink" Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  BorderThickness="2" MouseWheel="Border_MouseWheel" Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransform="{Binding MainTransform}"> 
<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1" Height="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Height}" Width="{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Width}"> 
    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Canvas.Top="43" Canvas.Left="43" Fill="Red" Height="10" Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransform="{Binding TextTransform}" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"/> 
</Border>
```